# Spock- ignore spec method for a subclass

Tags: java, testing, groovy, tdd, spock

I have a test spec in `Spock` and I want to apply the same tests to another alternative with exception of one method. I extend the original spec, implement some custom stuff related to the alternative and would really like to exclude the execution of one test method.

I tried it with

```
@Ignore
def "Something must work in a certain way"() {
    //No implementation
}
```

but it seems that the method is called anyway.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: You can't override an inherited test method, nor can you ignore it (at least not without writing your own Spock extension).

Answer (score 86):

Verify the import statement for `@Ignore`. It should be imported from spock library instead of JUnit:

```
import spock.lang.Ignore
```

instead of

```
import org.junit.Ignore
```